# Change the date format with Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I’m looking to change the date format from 02/01/2021 to 2/1/21. What’s the possible solution?

I tried slicing:

```
start = 20 
df["year"]= df["year"].astype(str)
df["year"]= df["year"].str.slice(start)
```

I know it’s wrong, but I don’t have any idea how to do this.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in your question.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: Why are your two examples not the same day?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("02/01/2021", "%d/%m/%Y")

print(date.strftime("%d/%#m/%y"))
```

Output:

```
02/1/21
```

PS: you can use `-` instead of `#` if you are on Linux.

Comment: It works but how to make it dynamic not fixed, since it’s a dataframe.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHenedy It depends on your `df`. You can try to concatenate the date in one string like this `df['day'] + '/' + df['month'] + '/' + df['year']`

Comment: But this can’t get me the structure i need '2/1/21'. Can you explain a bit more with a code?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHenedy use `.lstrip(0)` on the string.